# TabControl position TabItems

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have TabControl.
I want move tabs to the left but window with content should not change the size.

[image]

Result:

[image]

My code:

```
<controls:TabControl Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" x:Name="MyTabControl" BorderBrush="Transparent" BorderThickness="0" Padding="0">
    <controls:TabControl.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="ClosableTabItem">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock x:Name="textBlockName" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding}"/>
                <HyperlinkButton Margin="6,0,0,0" x:Name="tabItemClose" VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                            Click="tabItemClose_Click">
                </HyperlinkButton>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </controls:TabControl.Resources>
    <controls:TabItem Header="Main" x:Name="MainTabItem" ToolTipService.ToolTip="Main" >
    </controls:TabItem>
</controls:TabControl>
```

Comment: You mean move the entire tabcontrol? Since it's in column 0, how is it'd width set? Either don't set the width or set horizontalalignment to left.

Comment: `I want move tabs to the left but window with content should not change the size`, explain this and we can help

Comment: @zackraiyan I need the tabs to be full-length Main Window, but the contents of the tabs are displayed as shown in the picture (green color)

Comment: please add another picture of exactly how u want it...I will help , i promise

Comment: I will add an answer , please be patient :)

Answer (score 0):

I won't really post a huge answer with a lot of `XAML` , rather i will give you some basic ideas of what you can do :)

1.Inside each tabitem,just add a grid and create two columns.Place every required element in the middle column and make sure the `Grid`'s `HorizontalAlignment` and `VerticalAlignment` are set to `Stretch`

[image]

2. You can customize the template of your tabcontrol and set required width/margin of `TabPenl`/`ContentPresenter`.

I think 1 is the easiest solution so far,if you want to use 2 , leave a comment and i'll add some helpful `XAML`

Hope this helps :)